# Color background doesn't work

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to change the background color in swing but it doesn't work!

I tried `this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);` and also tried `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);`

Here is a full code:

```
public class RoomGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // will first hold "Username:", later on "Enter message"
    private JLabel label;
    // to hold the Username and later on the messages
    private JTextField tf;
    // to hold the server address an the port number
    private JTextField tfServer, tfPort;
    // to Logout and get the list of the users
    private JButton logout,send, whoIsIn;
    // for the chat room
    private JTextArea ta;
    // if it is for connection
    private boolean connected;
    // the Client object
    private Client client;
    // the default port number
    private int defaultPort;
    private String defaultHost;

    private LoginGUI sg;
    private JList<String> whoIsInList,skills;
    private DefaultListModel<String> listModel,listModel2;

    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton btnStartChat;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane1,scrollPane2;




    /**
     * Create the application.
     */

    RoomGUI(String host, int port, String name,DefaultListModel<String> skillsList) {

        super("Chat Client");

        listModel2 = new DefaultListModel<>();
        //listModel2.addElement("USA"); 
        for(int i=0;i<skillsList.getSize();i++){
            listModel2.addElement(skillsList.getElementAt(i));
        }
        skills = new JList<>(listModel2);



        //loop on skillslist
        //      for(int i=0;i<skillsList.getSize();i++){
        //      System.out.println(skillsList.getElementAt(i));
        //      
        //      }

        defaultPort = port;
        defaultHost = host;


        //System.out.println(skillsList.getModel().getSize());
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 767, 708);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        ta = new JTextArea("Hi " +name+ "!! Welcome to the Chat room, Click \"Start chat\" to begin \n");
        ta.setBounds(190, 53, 525, 514);//525       



        scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane2.setBounds(190, 53, 525, 514);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane2);
        scrollPane2.setViewportView(ta);



        tf = new JTextField(name);
        tf.setEditable(false);
        tf.setBounds(190, 574, 425, 44);    
        frame.getContentPane().add(tf);




        send = new JButton("Send");
        send.setBounds(627, 574, 88, 44);
        send.addActionListener(this);
        frame.getContentPane().add(send);
        send.setEnabled(false);
        //btnNewButton.setEnabled(false);// you have to write something before being able to click "send"

        JLabel lblWhosOnline = new JLabel("Who's online:");
        lblWhosOnline.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 17));
        lblWhosOnline.setBounds(36, 13, 126, 38);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblWhosOnline);


        tfPort = new JTextField(" "+port);
        tfPort.setBounds(599, 13, 116, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tfPort);
        tfPort.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblPortNumber = new JLabel("Port number:");
        lblPortNumber.setBounds(503, 13, 92, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPortNumber);

        tfServer = new JTextField(" "+host);
        tfServer.setBounds(331, 13, 116, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tfServer);
        tfServer.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblHost = new JLabel("Server Address:");
        lblHost.setBounds(226, 13, 106, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblHost);

        logout = new JButton("logout");
        logout.setBounds(28, 626, 97, 27);
        logout.addActionListener(this);
        frame.getContentPane().add(logout);

        btnStartChat = new JButton("Start chat");
        btnStartChat.setBounds(140, 626, 97, 27);
        btnStartChat.addActionListener(this);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnStartChat);



        //create the model and add elements 
        listModel = new DefaultListModel<>(); 
        //      listModel.addElement("USA"); 
        //      listModel.addElement("India"); 
        //      listModel.addElement("Vietnam"); 



        scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane1.setBounds(23, 53, 156, 565);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane1);


        whoIsIn = new JButton("Who is in");
        whoIsIn.addActionListener(this);
        whoIsIn.setBounds(252, 626, 97, 27);
        frame.getContentPane().add(whoIsIn);


        //create the list 
        whoIsInList = new JList<>(listModel);
        //frame.getContentPane().add(whoIsInList);
        whoIsInList.setBounds(12, 53, 366, 563);
        scrollPane1.setViewportView(whoIsInList);

        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    // called by the Client to append text in the TextArea 
    void append(String str) {

        ta.append(str);
        ta.setCaretPosition(ta.getText().length() - 1);
    }

    // Added by me: called by the Client to append text in the Jlist 
    void append2(String str) {
        listModel2 = new DefaultListModel<>();
        System.out.println("appppppppppen222");
        String[] q={};
        try{
            //((DefaultListModel)whoIsInList.getModel()).clear();
            //whoIsInList.setListData(listModel2);


            //whoIsInList.setListData(q);
            listModel.addElement(str);

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
    // called by the GUI is the connection failed
    // we reset our buttons, label, textfield
    void connectionFailed() {
        //login.setEnabled(true);
        logout.setEnabled(false);
        //whoIsIn.setEnabled(false);
        //label.setText("Enter your username below");
        tf.setText("Anonymous-tf");
        // reset port number and host name as a construction time
        tfPort.setText("" + defaultPort);
        tfServer.setText(defaultHost);
        // let the user change them
        tfServer.setEditable(false);
        tfPort.setEditable(false);
        // don't react to a <CR> after the username
        tf.removeActionListener(this);
        connected = false;
    }

    /*
     * Button or JTextField clicked
     */

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object o = e.getSource();


        if(o == logout) {
            System.out.println("You logged out");
            frame.setVisible(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Bye bye!");
            client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.LOGOUT, ""));    
            return;
        }

        if(o == btnStartChat) {
            // ok it is a connection request
            btnStartChat.setEnabled(false);
            tf.setEditable(true);
            send.setEnabled(true);
            String username = tf.getText().trim();
            // empty username ignore it
            if(username.length() == 0)
                return;
            // empty serverAddress ignore it
            String server = tfServer.getText().trim();
            if(server.length() == 0)
                return;
            // empty or invalid port numer, ignore it
            String portNumber = tfPort.getText().trim();
            if(portNumber.length() == 0)
                return;
            int port = 0;
            try {
                port = Integer.parseInt(portNumber);
            }
            catch(Exception en) {
                return;   // nothing I can do if port number is not valid
            }


            String[] s=new String[listModel2.getSize()];
            for(int i=0;i<listModel2.getSize();i++){
            s[i]=listModel2.getElementAt(i);

            }
            frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

            // try creating a new Client with GUI
            /*client = new Client(server, port, username, this,s);*///<--------------------------return this line after
            // test if we can start the Client
            if(!client.start()) 
                return;
            tf.setText("");
            //label.setText("Enter your message below");
            connected = true;

            // disable login button
            //login.setEnabled(false);
            // enable the 2 buttons
            logout.setEnabled(true);
            //whoIsIn.setEnabled(true);
            // disable the Server and Port JTextField
            tfServer.setEditable(false);
            tfPort.setEditable(false);

            // Action listener for when the user enter a message
            tf.addActionListener(this);

        }

        if(o==send) {
            //System.out.println("Check if connected");
            // just have to send the message
            client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.MESSAGE, tf.getText()));             
            tf.setText("");
            return;
        }

        // if it the who is in button
        if(o == whoIsIn) {
            System.out.println("Check whosin button");
            ((DefaultListModel)whoIsInList.getModel()).clear();
            client.sendMessage(new ChatMessage(ChatMessage.WHOISIN, ""));               
            return;
        }


    }

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DefaultListModel<String> skillsList = new DefaultListModel<>();;
        new ClientGUI("localhost",1500,"Some name",skillsList);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you write 100's of lines of code to test setting the background color? Start by creating a frame and set the background. Then try adding one component and see what happens. Then if it doesn't work you have simple code to post. We are not interested in looking at the code for your entire application. This is called an [mcve]. The point of the `MCVE` is to simplify the problem BEFORE you post a question.

Comment: in the main method you are calling ClientGui but your class name is RoomGUI. how does this work? also, why are you extending Jframe and also have a private JFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main method you are calling `ClientGui` but your class name is `RoomGUI`.  Also, why are you extending `Jframe` and also have a private `JFrame`?